# Specify Different Command Prompt for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, ide, visual-studio-2019, tooling

In Visual Studio 2017 or 2019 is it possible to have a different program, say gitbash or powershell, run for:

> **Team Explorer > Actions > Open Command Prompt**

So far, I have only found instructions to [customize the default developer command prompt](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/07/22/customize-the-command-prompt/). I seek to use a different prompt entirely.

---

**UPDATE**:
To illustrate what I mean by 'Actions` under Team Explorer here's a small screen shot:

[image: Screen fragment showing the 'Actions' menu in Team Explorer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Open Command Line](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.OpenCommandLine) extension.

You can define multiple command line options available from the solution explorer context menu, including a default which has a keyboard mapping.

(I don't know what you mean by actions in Team Explorer: do you have a not-git VCS option set?)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this extension.  It's an option to consider.  I've added a screenshot to help identify what I am referring to as Team Explorer > Actions.

Comment: @TrevorReid The git changes tool window... (yes it can be reached from Team Explorer, but I run with a separate instance (the arrow top right allows it to be opened separately), I know of no way to customise that... but Open Command Line's Alt-Space to open a default does work even with the focus in the changes window.

Comment: works great.  The only drawback I found to this extension is that its default keyboard shortcut is ALT + SPACE.  This is a standard shortcut to the Window Buttons (Restore, Move, Size, etc.) across Windows.  Fortunately, the extension provides a setting to customize this shortcut in its Options Window under Environment -> Keyboard.  It's just sort of an unfortunate default. Ultimately though, this gets me where I need to be.

Comment: Extensions are great, but they add an extra overhead (sometimes low, but never zero). It would be great if M$ absorbed those main features into the product itself.